# Replace specific values in a column in data frame

Tags: r, replace

I really apologize for such a basic question and I have spent 20 minutes trying to figure this out. Example:

```
x <- sample(c("1","2"), 100, replace = TRUE)
y <- sample(c("3","4"), 100, replace = TRUE)
xy <- cbind(x,y)
```

Now I want to replace all "2"s with "0"s in the x column. On my real data, I need to recode all the females coded as "2" as "0".

I have tried:

```
xy$x[,xy$x == 2] <- 0

xy[xy$x== 2] <- 0

women <- xy$x== 2
xy[women,] <- 0
```

Neither of these work. The first two give an error, the last one replaces the whole row with zeros. I have searched a lot on this site but there has to be a very simple solution (not that the difficult worked anyway).

EDIT:

My apologies for using a sample not equal to my actual issue. How do I do it with this sample?

```
x <- sample(c("1","2"), 100, replace = TRUE)
y <- sample(c("3","4"), 100, replace = TRUE)
xy <- cbind(x,y)
```

Thanks!

Comment: Just use `replace(xy, xy == "2", "0")`

Comment: Or `xy[xy[, 1] == 2, 1] <- 0`

Comment: Thanks guys, it works on the sample I provided, but not in my original data. What if the second column was also full of 1 and 2s? Because this function replaces all values equal to 2 in the data frame. I wish to only change the ones in the first column. I apologize for providing and incorrect sample, edited my post.

Comment: @JachymDvorak So your sample is not good enough.

Comment: You create character values for your example, then try to match those with numeric values. `"2" != 2`!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several problems:

- `xy` is matrix but the code is using $ which is for data frames.
- if `xy` were a data frame then `xy$x` is one dimensional but the code in the question is attempting to index it with 2 dimeensions
- the code in the question using `women` is attempting to set the entire row to 0
- to make the example reproducible the question should include `set.seed` so that the same random numbes are used each time it is invoked

This variation of the code in the question works.

If you are using a version of R that earlier than R 4.0 it is important to use `stringAsFactors=FALSE`; however, for later versions that argument is not needed although it won't hurt if you leave it in.

```
xy <- as.data.frame(xy, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
xy$x[xy$x == 2] <- 0
```

For the code involving `women` assuming again that `xy` is a data frame:

```
women <- xy$x== 2
xy[women, "x"] <- 0
```

If `xy` is a matrix as in the question then this works:

```
xy[xy[, "x"] == 2, "x"] <- 0
```

This works whether `xy` is a matrix or data frame and returns a data.frame:

```
transform(xy, x = replace(x, x == 2, 0))
```

or

```
transform(xy, x = ifelse(x == 2, 0, x))
```

Comment: Thanks a ton. The last line works, I have successfuly changed the values in my original sample!